# javascript conflict

Tags: javascript, footer

I am having a JavaScript which is used for marquee, I want to use this in my wordpress site.

But this java script is conflicting with my wordpress, I am using this in footer, but just the `div` area is getting loaded, the marquee in it is not working.

Here is my code:

```
<div class="marq">
<script type="text/javascript">

/***********************************************
* Conveyor belt slideshow script- © Dynamic Drive DHTML code library (www.dynamicdrive.com)
* This notice MUST stay intact for legal use
* Visit Dynamic Drive at http://www.dynamicdrive.com/ for full source code
***********************************************/


//Specify the slider's width (in pixels)
var sliderwidth="900px"
//Specify the slider's height
var sliderheight="100px"
//Specify the slider's slide speed (larger is faster 1-10)
var slidespeed=5
//configure background color:
slidebgcolor="#FFFFFF"

//Specify the slider's images
var leftrightslide=new Array()
var finalslide=''

leftrightslide[0]='<a href="#" target="_blank" style="color:#FFFFFF;"><img src="images/management-paradise-logo.jpg" style="height:80px; opacity:0.4;filter:alpha(opacity=40)"onmouseover="this.style.opacity=1;this.filters.alpha.opacity=100"onmouseout="this.style.opacity=0.4;this.filters.alpha.opacity=40"></a><img src="images/line.png" style="height:80px; padding-left:30px; padding-right:30px; padding-bottom:10px;"/>'
leftrightslide[1]='<a href="#" target="_blank" style="color:#FFFFFF;"><img src="images/MBAS.IN.jpg"  style="opacity:0.4;filter:alpha(opacity=40)"onmouseover="this.style.opacity=1;this.filters.alpha.opacity=100"onmouseout="this.style.opacity=0.4;this.filters.alpha.opacity=40"></a><img src="images/line.png " style="height:80px; padding-left:30px; padding-right:30px; padding-bottom:10px;"/>'
leftrightslide[2]='<a href="#" target="_blank" style="color:#FFFFFF;"><img src="images/bms.co.in.jpg" style="height:80px; opacity:0.4;filter:alpha(opacity=40)"onmouseover="this.style.opacity=1;this.filters.alpha.opacity=100"onmouseout="this.style.opacity=0.4;this.filters.alpha.opacity=40"></a><img src="images/line.png" style="height:80px; padding-left:30px; padding-right:30px; padding-bottom:10px;"/>'
leftrightslide[3]='<a href="#" target="_blank" style="color:#FFFFFF;"><img src="images/mbas.co.in.jpg" style="height:80px; opacity:0.4;filter:alpha(opacity=40)"onmouseover="this.style.opacity=1;this.filters.alpha.opacity=100"onmouseout="this.style.opacity=0.4;this.filters.alpha.opacity=40"></a><img src="images/line.png" style="height:80px; padding-left:30px; padding-right:30px; padding-bottom:10px;"/>'
leftrightslide[4]='<a href="#" target="_blank" style="color:#FFFFFF;"><img src="images/MCAS.jpg" style="height:80px; opacity:0.4;filter:alpha(opacity=40)"onmouseover="this.style.opacity=1;this.filters.alpha.opacity=100"onmouseout="this.style.opacity=0.4;this.filters.alpha.opacity=40"></a><img src="images/line.png" style="height:80px; padding-left:30px; padding-right:30px; padding-bottom:10px;"/>'
leftrightslide[5]='<a href="#" target="_blank" style="color:#FFFFFF;"><img src="images/casestudy.co.in.jpg" style="height:80px; opacity:0.4;filter:alpha(opacity=40)"onmouseover="this.style.opacity=1;this.filters.alpha.opacity=100"onmouseout="this.style.opacity=0.4;this.filters.alpha.opacity=40"></a><img src="images/line.png" style="height:80px; padding-left:30px; padding-right:30px; padding-bottom:10px;"/>'
leftrightslide[6]='<a href="#" target="_blank" style="color:#FFFFFF;"><img src="images/ONLINEMBA.CO.IN.jpg" style="height:80px; opacity:0.4;filter:alpha(opacity=40)"onmouseover="this.style.opacity=1;this.filters.alpha.opacity=100"onmouseout="this.style.opacity=0.4;this.filters.alpha.opacity=40"></a><img src="images/line.png" style="height:80px; padding-left:30px; padding-right:30px; padding-bottom:10px;"/>'
leftrightslide[7]='<a href="#" target="_blank" style="color:#FFFFFF;"><img src="images/BAF.jpg" style="height:80px; opacity:0.4;filter:alpha(opacity=40)"onmouseover="this.style.opacity=1;this.filters.alpha.opacity=100"onmouseout="this.style.opacity=0.4;this.filters.alpha.opacity=40"></a><img src="images/line.png" style="height:80px; padding-left:30px; padding-right:30px; padding-bottom:10px;"/>'
leftrightslide[8]='<a href="#" target="_blank" style="color:#FFFFFF;"><img src="images/BBI.jpg" style="height:80px; opacity:0.4;filter:alpha(opacity=40)"onmouseover="this.style.opacity=1;this.filters.alpha.opacity=100"onmouseout="this.style.opacity=0.4;this.filters.alpha.opacity=40"></a><img src="images/line.png" style="height:80px; padding-left:30px; padding-right:30px; padding-bottom:10px;"/>'
leftrightslide[9]='<a href="#" target="_blank" style="color:#FFFFFF;"><img src="images/BFM.jpg" style="height:80px; opacity:0.4;filter:alpha(opacity=40)"onmouseover="this.style.opacity=1;this.filters.alpha.opacity=100"onmouseout="this.style.opacity=0.4;this.filters.alpha.opacity=40"></a><img src="images/line.png" style="height:80px; padding-left:30px; padding-right:30px; padding-bottom:10px;"/>'
leftrightslide[10]='<a href="#" target="_blank" style="color:#FFFFFF;"><img src="images/BMM.jpg" style="height:80px; opacity:0.4;filter:alpha(opacity=40)"onmouseover="this.style.opacity=1;this.filters.alpha.opacity=100"onmouseout="this.style.opacity=0.4;this.filters.alpha.opacity=40"></a><img src="images/line.png" style="height:80px; padding-left:30px; padding-right:30px; padding-bottom:10px;"/>'
leftrightslide[11]='<a href="#" target="_blank" style="color:#FFFFFF;"><img src="images/U-K.IN.jpg" style="height:80px; opacity:0.4;filter:alpha(opacity=40)"onmouseover="this.style.opacity=1;this.filters.alpha.opacity=100"onmouseout="this.style.opacity=0.4;this.filters.alpha.opacity=40"></a><img src="images/line.png" style="height:80px; padding-left:30px; padding-right:30px; padding-bottom:10px;"/>'

//Specify gap between each image (use HTML):
var imagegap=" "

//Specify pixels gap between each slideshow rotation (use integer):
var slideshowgap=5


////NO NEED TO EDIT BELOW THIS LINE////////////

var copyspeed=slidespeed
leftrightslide='<nobr>'+leftrightslide.join(imagegap)+'</nobr>'
var iedom=document.all||document.getElementById
if (iedom)
document.write('<span id="temp" style="visibility:hidden;position:absolute;top:-100px;left:-9000px">'+leftrightslide+'</span>')
var actualwidth=''
var cross_slide, ns_slide

function fillup(){
if (iedom){
cross_slide=document.getElementById? document.getElementById("test2") : document.all.test2
cross_slide2=document.getElementById? document.getElementById("test3") : document.all.test3
cross_slide.innerHTML=cross_slide2.innerHTML=leftrightslide
actualwidth=document.all? cross_slide.offsetWidth : document.getElementById("temp").offsetWidth
cross_slide2.style.left=actualwidth+slideshowgap+"px"
}
else if (document.layers){
ns_slide=document.ns_slidemenu.document.ns_slidemenu2
ns_slide2=document.ns_slidemenu.document.ns_slidemenu3
ns_slide.document.write(leftrightslide)
ns_slide.document.close()
actualwidth=ns_slide.document.width
ns_slide2.left=actualwidth+slideshowgap
ns_slide2.document.write(leftrightslide)
ns_slide2.document.close()
}
lefttime=setInterval("slideleft()",30)
}
window.onload=fillup

function slideleft(){
if (iedom){
if (parseInt(cross_slide.style.left)>(actualwidth*(-1)+8))
cross_slide.style.left=parseInt(cross_slide.style.left)-copyspeed+"px"
else
cross_slide.style.left=parseInt(cross_slide2.style.left)+actualwidth+slideshowgap+"px"

if (parseInt(cross_slide2.style.left)>(actualwidth*(-1)+8))
cross_slide2.style.left=parseInt(cross_slide2.style.left)-copyspeed+"px"
else
cross_slide2.style.left=parseInt(cross_slide.style.left)+actualwidth+slideshowgap+"px"

}
else if (document.layers){
if (ns_slide.left>(actualwidth*(-1)+8))
ns_slide.left-=copyspeed
else
ns_slide.left=ns_slide2.left+actualwidth+slideshowgap

if (ns_slide2.left>(actualwidth*(-1)+8))
ns_slide2.left-=copyspeed
else
ns_slide2.left=ns_slide.left+actualwidth+slideshowgap
}
}


if (iedom||document.layers){
with (document){
document.write('<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"><td>')
if (iedom){
write('<div style="position:relative;width:'+sliderwidth+';height:'+sliderheight+';overflow:hidden">')
write('<div style="position:absolute;width:'+sliderwidth+';height:'+sliderheight+';background-color:'+slidebgcolor+'" onMouseover="copyspeed=0" onMouseout="copyspeed=slidespeed">')
write('<div id="test2" style="position:absolute;left:0px;top:0px"></div>')
write('<div id="test3" style="position:absolute;left:-1000px;top:0px"></div>')
write('</div></div>')
}
else if (document.layers){
write('<ilayer width='+sliderwidth+' height='+sliderheight+' name="ns_slidemenu" bgColor='+slidebgcolor+'>')
write('<layer name="ns_slidemenu2" left=0 top=0 onMouseover="copyspeed=0" onMouseout="copyspeed=slidespeed"></layer>')
write('<layer name="ns_slidemenu3" left=0 top=0 onMouseover="copyspeed=0" onMouseout="copyspeed=slidespeed"></layer>')
write('</ilayer>')
}
document.write('</td></table>')
}
}
</script></div>
```

How can I integrate this with my wordpress site?

Comment: Switch to a [jQuery script](http://plugins.jquery.com/plugin-tags/marquee)?

Comment: @t31os The reason I adopted this code, because this goes in a loop, I mean at the end of each marquee a space is left then after that space the marquee starts, I want no space direct flow,
Is their any jquery for that? and is there any way to integrated the current javascript into wp?

Comment: You have to tell us what is wrong with the javascript or provide a link to your site. We can't tell what is wrong with your js just with a block of code. For example, is a javascript error being thrown? If so what line? What is the error?

Comment: @mrtsherman Their is nothing wrong with my javascript, it is conflicting with my wordpress, all my other jquery stops working, if I insert this javascript

Comment: @ntechi - then most likely this javascript has a compile error in it. you need to look at it in a debugger and see what the error is. or if you can post a link someone here can help you identify the error.

Comment: @mrtsherman Is their any Jquery in a continue loop, I saw some jqueries, but it has a blank space after the last image, I want in a continue loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That script looks very old and obtrusive and it doesn't output a marquee, but a slideshow.

There already are hundreads of themes with a slideshow built in, as well as many newer jQuery plugins which you can switch to.

If you're still convinced this particular script is worth the time to fix, install [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) to see the exact error.

Comment: Also, don't hard-code scripts directly into the footer; rather, put them in a separate file, and then register and enqueue them via `wp_register_script()` and `wp_enqueue_script()`. (Note: `wp_enqueue_script()` includes an `$in_footer` argument, for outputting scripts via the `wp_footer()` hook.